# HTTP request safe?

Tags: php, iphone, xml, asihttprequest

I am sending http request to my server using ASIHTTPRequest library but I don't know if it obfuscates the request data. Also on the sever side, I am creating an XML file and response back to the device using php. What is the safe way to form an XML document and send back to the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only safe way to connect to a webserver is by using SSL/https.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend SSL and/or [XML Signatures](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/08/xmldsig.html)

Answer (score 0):

Anything sent over just http is sent in clear text.  Anyone can see your traffic on any part of the route from you to the destination.  This is why facebook/twitter and a number of sites have switched to an https preferred model.